# Unable to login to my nytimes account using requests in python

Tags: python

I am trying to send a post request using the nice Requests library in Python. I am sending the payload, as shown in the code, however, the `r.text` print statement shows the html dump of the myaccount.nytimes.com page, which is not what I want. Any one knows what's happening?

```
payload = {
    'userid': 'myemail',
    'password': 'mypass'
}

s = requests.session()
r = s.post('https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login/?URI=http://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/13/opinion/on-long-island-a-worthy-plan-for-coastal-flooding.html?partner=rss', data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Hi Ali, how did you get this to work after all? I can parse the page and get the hidden values but not sure how to authenticate using this info and my credentials?

Comment: The answer below worked for me @StefanJansen

Comment: Did you add the token you got from the login page to your `s.post()` request above, or to the session itself? Subsequent page requests as `s.get()` without parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of hidden `<input>` fields that you are omitting from your form:

1. `is_continue`
2. `expires`
3. `token`

`token` looks like it would be required, maybe the others aren't.

And possibly `remember` which is the "remember me" tickbox at the bottom of the form.

Starting with `token` try incrementally adding fields until it works.

**Edit from comment:** Token is provided to you when you first access the login page. Thus you need to do an initial GET to https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login/, parse the HTML (BeautifulSoup?) to get the token (and other fields), then POST back to the server. Or you could use mechanize to handle this more easily.

Comment: Token is provided to you when you first access the login page. Thus you need to do an initial `GET` to `https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login/`, parse the HTML (BeautifulSoup?) to get the token (and other fields), then `POST` back to the server. Or you could use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to handle this more easily.

Comment: Thanks, it all worked. I added your comment in the post for clarity.